# C++ cout formatting

Tags: c++

I am working on a small program that takes uppercase letters and converts them to lowercase. I have this accomplished, but when outputting the result it shows before my text when it should be after. How should I go about fixing this? 
Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string users_word;

    cout << "Please enter a word: ";
    getline(cin, users_word);

    cout << "You entered the word: " << users_word << endl;

    char i = 0;
    char c = 0;

    while (users_word[i])
    {
        c = users_word[i];
        putchar(tolower(c));
        i ++;
    }
    cout << "Your word in lowercase is: " << c << endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
Please enter a word: Hello
You entered the word: Hello
helloYour word in lowercase is:
```

I am trying to figure out how to get "hello" afterwards.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `cout`. You first ask to print `hello` (using `putchar()` in a loop), and only later you ask to print the rest of the sentence with `cout << "Your word...`. You should probably put `cout <<` before the loop or store the lowercase tring in another variable, that you can print later.

Comment: `cout << "Your word in lowercase is: " << c << endl;` Note: that `c` is a single character not a string. And the single character you print here is `\0`

Comment: Thank you all, this helped. Simple miss on my part not following the code.

Answer (score 1):

By calling `putchar()` directly, you are bypassing any buffering that `std::cout` does internally.  You are outputting characters to the terminal before the `cout` buffer is flushed to the terminal.

Also, even if you were using `std::cout` instead of `putchar()`, you are still outputting the lowercase characters before you output `"Your word in lowercase is: "`.  You need to output that message before entering your loop, not outputting it after the loop.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string users_word;

    cout << "Please enter a word: ";
    getline(cin, users_word);

    cout << "You entered the word: " << users_word << endl;

    cout << "Your word in lowercase is: ";

    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < users_word.size(); ++i)
    {
        char c = users_word[i];

        //putchar(tolower(c));
        cout.put(tolower(c));
        // or: cout << (char) tolower(c);
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `while` loop `implicitly` redirects the lower chars to `std::out` already.

Thus,

```
cout << "Your word in lowercase is: " << c << endl;
```

will appear your lower text in front of `Your word in lowercase is:`. Just move the `cout << "Your word in lowercase is: ";` before `while` statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ...
  cout << "Your word in lowercase is: ";
  while (users_word[i])
  {
    c = users_word[i];
    putchar(tolower(c));
    i++;
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```